# Requirements on array of objects

Tags: json, jsonschema

I have written schema:

```
{
  "type": "array",
  "items": {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
      "alarms": {
        "type": "integer"
      },
      "events": {
        "type": "integer"
      },
      "statistics": {
        "type": "integer"
      }
    }
  },
  "oneOf": [
    {
    "required":["alarms"],
     "required":["events"],
     "required":["statistics"]
    } 
  ]
}
```

and the schema unfortunately allows:

```
[{alarms: 1, events: 1}, {events:1}, {statistics:3}]
```

and my goal is to properly validate only:

```
[{alarms: 1, {events:3}, {statistics:7}]
```

I was trying, but without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [documentation](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/structuring.html) of JSON Schema and Your example, what You have to do is to validate "Items" object. Also You had a bug in "oneOf" validation. You should add 3 objects into "oneOf" array and You had only one object with 3 same parameters.

```
    {
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "alarms": {
            "type": "integer"
          },
          "events": {
            "type": "integer"
          },
          "statistics": {
            "type": "integer"
          }
        },
        "oneOf": [
         {
           "required":["alarms"]
         },
         {
           "required":["events"]
         },
         {
           "required":["statistics"]
         }
        ]
      },
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

By looking at your examples, it seems that what you're trying to avoid is having objects with multiple properties. If that is the case, here's how I would do it:

```json
{
    "type": "array",
    "items": {
        "type": "object",
        "patternProperties": {
            "^(alarms|events|statistics)$": {
                "type": "integer"
            }
        },
        "additionalProperties": false,
        "minProperties": 1,
        "maxProperties": 1
    }
}
```

Comment: "By looking at your examples, it seems that what you're trying to avoid is having objects with multiple properties." Yes! Thanks!